# Is adding a function of time to a ARMA model still a linear time series model?

Tags: time-series

I wonder if the following model is a linear or nonlinear time series model:

$$
X_t = d(t) + \sum_{i=1}^p a_i X_{t-i} + \sum_{i=0}^q b_i e_{t-i}
$$

when $d(t) = ct$, $d(t) = e^t$, $d(t)=sin(t)$, and $d(t) = t^3$?

According to the definitons in Tsay's Financial Time Series, I guess they are linear because $E(X_t|F_t), F_t=\{X_{t-1}, \dots, X_0\}$  is linear in $X_{t-1}, \dots, X_0$, and $Var(X_t |F_t)$ doesn't depend on $t$. But $X_t$ may be not linear in $t$, so I am not sure.

p.s. There are two definitions from the book (I just used the second one), which I guess are equivalent?

Definition 1:

[image]

[image]

Definition 2:

[image]

Comment: Note that linear in such contexts usually means "linear in parameters". d(t) in your example formulations doesn't seem to contain parameters at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. You are dealing with ARMAX model, and X - exogenous variables - includes your time components. The exogenous variables must be stationary, and $ct$ is not.

There are other time series methods, such as state space models, which work with non-stationary series, but ARMAX can't.

Comment: Thanks. Are the models in my post still linear models?

Comment: $ct$ is linear. $e^t$ is linearized if you present is as $ce^t$ with a linear constraint $c=1$.

Comment: thanks. how can you tell that from either of the two definitions given in my post?

Comment: A linearized function is a function of a form $\sum_ic_if_i(x_1,x_2,...,x_N)$, a liner one is $\sum_ic_ix_i$

Comment: This is incorrect. Adding deterministic terms, including linear trends does not make a model nonstationary. Nonstationarity relates to _stochastic_ trends.

Comment: @fgnu, wrong. The deterministic trend means that the means is changing, this will not work with ARMAX. Check the definitions before making broad statements.

Comment: @Aksakal Can you define _will not work_?